# Subgroup generated by union of two maximal compact subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, matrix-decomposition, p-adic-number-theory

Let us denote by $G:= GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p), G_0:= GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p), g:= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\p& 0\end{bmatrix}$ and by $G_1:= g G_0 g^{-1}$. I want to know if we have a good description of the subgroup generated inside $GL_2(Q_p)$ by union of $G_0$ and $G_1$, i.e., $<G_0\cup G_1>\subseteq G$. First of all by restriction on determinants we know any matrix in this subgroup will have determinant in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$. Is that the only restriction, that is, can we get any matrices inside $G$ with determinant in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$?

More generally if we have $K_1:= hG_0h^{-1}$ and $K_2:= hG_1h^{-1}$ with $h \in GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ then what can we say about $<K_1\cup K_2>$?

I have done some computations which shows I can make p-adic valuation of certain entries of the matrices in this group arbitrarily small, but not entirely sure how to proceed concretely from there or if this is a reasonable question to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Won't  the $LU \implies N^\top D N$ decomposition ($N$ upper triangular with diagonal $= 1$) say $\langle  g N(\mathbb{Z}_p)^\top D(\mathbb{Z}_p) N(\mathbb{Z}_p) g^{-1},N(\mathbb{Z}_p)^\top D(\mathbb{Z}_p) N(\mathbb{Z}_p) \rangle = N(\mathbb{Q}_p)^\top D(\mathbb{Z}_p) N(\mathbb{Q}_p)$

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't follow your comment completely.  Can you please elaborate? Thanks,